# Disk load at 100% and PC is extremely slow

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, freeze

I'm experiencing this problem where my disk load is always high. I've seen other people with this same problem here but their solutions are not solving my problem.

Let me explain: From last night to this morning, my computer would freeze when i was executing various processes at the same time (let's say browsing the internet, listening music and playing games).

I've installed the Trial Version of HDTune and saw that my HDD was at 100% load even without any background process running. Checking its health with this same program (S.M.A.R.T), I've got a bad news: it had thousands of damaged sectors.

Alright, s*** happens and so i went looking for a new HDD. Got a brand new one this same evening and already installed my Windows 7 Ultimate OS on it.

After an hour installing I realized maybe my old HDD was not the problem, since it doesn't ordinarily take too long to install Windows 7 with my rig.

I tried changing my RAM to another slot and ran a MemTest on it to see if it was a memory issue, but as you may guess, it was not.
I also tried changing my SATA Cable, but no deal: still slow!

Right know i have this new HDD mounted on my computer but i can't run even a low graphics game that my computer tottaly freezes. 
Any thoughts on this? Maybe motherboard problem? Processor?

Thanks in advance.

My specs are:

- Asus M5A97 Evo R2.0 Motherboard
- AMD FX-8320 Processor
- 2x 4GB Kingston DDR3 1333Mhz Memory
- Seagate 1TB HDD SATA3
- Nvidia GTX650Ti Boost VGA

Comment: sounds like the sata controller might be borked

Comment: What does your BIOS say about the operation mode of your SATA port the HDD operates on (AHCI, IDE, RAID)?

Comment: @Keltari is there a way to check for problems on my controller?

Comment: @Foosh i'll be checking that and post here.

Comment: While you're in there might want to check your power saving settings.  As to diagnosing your controller, not sure of anything beyond trying to fry another HDD (not exactly cost effective). You might want to switch the port your HDD is using and see if you get the same result.  Some ASUS boards use a different controller for their highest 2 SATA ports.

Comment: Go into your BIOS and there should be a disk/sata controller mode. It'll have some options like IDE, SATA and/or RAID. If it's already set to AHCI then Windows will have been installed and activated the AHCI functionality. This will rule this out.

Comment: @Foosh both controllers are configured to AHCI. I've tried changing to the superior SATA Ports and now im gonna give it a try.

Comment: @Foosh seems like its ok now. I think one of my SATA controllers is damaged.

Comment: Do you have the latest AMD drivers from their website? Do not trust what Windows downloads automatically.